# How to select for certain data in a .txt file

Tags: r, text

I have a .txt import file from a weather station using some pretty advanced code, and I need to sort based on one area of content within each line. Here's a few lines:

```
13:30:00.587: <- $GPGGA,183000.30,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.5,M,-33.4,M,,*68
13:30:00.683: <- $GPGLL,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,183000.40,A,A*72  
13:30:00.779: <- $GPVTG,159.6,T,163.2,M,0.1,N,0.1,K,A*2E
```

I basically need to be able to group together all lines with a $GPGGA, and do the same for $GPGLL, $GPVTG, and I believe 6 other types of entries that repeat. group_by() does work, nor do select() or sort() for obvious reasons. The formatting here is clearly not in any organized table format, making this very difficult for me. How do I do this?

Here's the code I used to import the original file (I replaced my actual username with "my username"):

```
filefolder <-"C:\\Users\\"my username"\\Downloads\\"
Weather_data = paste(filefolder, "Jul_13_2021_Weatherstation_Test_File.txt", sep = "")
Weather_data <- read.delim("Jul_13_2021_Weatherstation_Test_File.txt")
```

And here's what I have so far in my attempt:

[Screenshot of what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc9sC.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc9sC.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSlzf.png][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSlzf.png%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 0):

As you say there is no organisation in the table. I would suggest doing something with regular expressions:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("13:30:00.587: <- $GPGGA,183000.30,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.5,M,-33.4,M,,*68",
"13:30:00.683: <- $GPGLL,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,183000.40,A,A*72",
"13:30:00.779: <- $GPVTG,159.6,T,163.2,M,0.1,N,0.1,K,A*2E"))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Entry = gsub(".*\\$([A-Z]+),.*", "\\1", text)) %>%
  group_by(Entry)
```

Comment: the only formatting of any sort I can say exists is that the number string at the row start is a timestamp, and the rest of the data is a string of outputs, not consistent from one line to the next categorically, produced by a sonic weather instrument. I tried what you suggested, I can get a data frame but the filtering mechanism doesn't work to extract entire lines including identical $XXXXX character strings near the beginning of each line.

Comment: Can you show me the output that you got? I cannot exactly know why we get different results otherwise.

Comment: text
<chr>
13:30:00.587: <- $GPGGA,183000.30,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.5,M,-33.4,M,,*68 
13:30:00.683: <- $GPGLL,4415.6243,N,08823.9769,W,183000.40,A,A*72 
13:30:00.779: <- $GPVTG,159.6,T,163.2,M,0.1,N,0.1,K,A*2E 
13:30:01.578: <- $GPGGA,183001.30,4415.6242,N,08823.9769,W,1,7,1.7,225.9,M,-33.4,M,,*64                          That's the first column

Comment: The other two are:                                                                                                   
$GPGGA
<chr>
"$GPGGA"
<chr>
GPGGA 
GPGLL 
GPVTG 
GPGGA                                                                                                                                       and:                                                                                                                                           "$GPGGA"
<chr>
$GPGGA
$GPGGA
$GPGGA
$GPGGA

Comment: I cannot seem to post screen caps for some reason, that's the best I can muster

Comment: Please edit the original post so you can use formatting and screen caps. And show me what you used to import the data from your .txt file

Comment: I've updated the original with the import code and a screen cap of the code I attempted thus far: a small snippet used to see if I could create a data frame, and your suggested addition.

Comment: The code in your screen cap does not match the code I suggested. The function "exists" is not used to check for strings, it is used to check if a certain object exists (like for example: df)

Comment: Yes I realize I forgot to reinsert it after having tried another (failed) option. It should be correct now. I will also add the output I gave you the first time was the result of what you provided: that part was correct.

Comment: You changed the name of "Entry", which is fine. But if you use special symbols in a column name you have the use single backticks ("`") instead of double quotes. If you use double quotes R will think that it is a string, which it is not. The correct way would be `$GPGGA` if you want to go that path although I question why you would want that :).

Lastly I wanted to notify you that the output is not visible in your second screen cap.

Comment: I managed to get it functioning by adding a filter line to leave me just the GPGGA lines, something which I can replicate for each of the other 8 categories I need to make of the txt file. Thank you for all of your help!